# Округление картинок UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

Я пытаюсь округлить изображения в tableView, но почему-то округлить не удается. В чем может быть дело?

```
class Picture {
    var picture: UIImage?
    
    init(picture: UIImage?) {
        self.picture = picture
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var MyTableView = UITableView()
    let identifer = "MyCell"
    var array = ["1": "One", "2":"two", "3":"three", "4":"four", "5":"five", "6":"six", "7":"seven"]
    var arrayKeys = [String]()
    var myPicture = [Picture]()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createTable()
        MyTableView.delegate = self
        MyTableView.dataSource = self
        arrayKeys = Array(array.keys).sorted{$0 < $1}
        myPicture.append(Picture(picture: UIImage(named: "1")))
        myPicture.append(Picture(picture: UIImage(named: "2")))
        myPicture.append(Picture(picture: UIImage(named: "3")))

    }
    func createTable() {
        MyTableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)
        MyTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifer)
        view.addSubview(MyTableView)
        MyTableView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifer, for: indexPath)
        if indexPath.row < array.count {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(arrayKeys[indexPath.row]) \(array[String(arrayKeys[indexPath.row])] ?? "")"
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = nil
        }
        
        if indexPath.row < myPicture.count {
            let data = myPicture[indexPath.row]
            cell.imageView?.image = data.picture
            cell.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = false
            cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.imageView?.frame.height ?? 0.0) / 2
            cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        } else {
            cell.imageView?.image = nil
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: @OlegSoloviev не работает

Comment: Если хотите, выложите куда-нибудь проект, на гитхаб например, я посмотрю.

Comment: 1) Установите брекпоинт на строке: cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.imageView?.frame.height ?? 0.0) / 2
2) Проверьте чему равна высота cell.imageView.frame.height